# How to get IMEI in Android Version 10 or 11?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**I want get IMEI in Android 10 or 11, but i'm getting exception Like this " java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10148 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers."**

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Sorry nothing get from this-  I am getting IMEI null in Android Q?